# I cannot find a fix for an error that keeps coming up in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

Xcode 15.1

```
Error: ld: Undefined Symbols 

ld: Undefined symbols:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARAnchor, referenced from:
       in ARSessionNative.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_AROrientationTrackingConfiguration, referenced from:
       in ARSessionNative.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARPlaneAnchor, referenced from:
       in ARSessionNative.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARSession, referenced from:
       in ARSessionNative.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARWorldTrackingConfiguration, referenced from:
       in ARSessionNative.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController, referenced from:
       in IOSHelper.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried a couple of different things in the arm64 and making changes inn the link support in Build settings. Nothing I have tried has worked. I am stuck as this is the last thing preventing my App from building.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

I tried what I mentioned in the above column. I am not sure what else to do as it does not seem like there are many fixes for it!

Comment: Looks like you are missing a few frameworks. Add the ARKit and MessageUI frameworks to your project.

Comment: Do I need to reopen it in Unity, or can I just download the missing files and add them to my Xcode? I am still fairly new and appreciate any help. This is the last thing I need to fix in order to get it to run.

Comment: I don't know anything about building a Unity app. For a normal Xcode iOS app you would add the frameworks to the project's General tab under the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section. Nothing needs to be downloaded.

Comment: So, I added the frameworks, but now, I have this issue:
Showing Recent Issues
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. It is also telling me through the path that at MapFileParser.sh: Permission Denied

Comment: line 2: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxxBackupSource/xxxxxxBackupSource/MapFileParser.sh: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.   None of the chmod commands I have been using work. It also tells me no such directory exists.

Comment: Please put all relevant details in your question, not in comments.